# Flatten sublists within a bigger list

Tags: list-manipulation

Really sorry if this question is a duplicate. I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

Here is a list I have:

```
{{{0. + 0.1875 I, 0. + 0.105469 I, 0. + 0.03125 I, 0. + 0.00390625 I, 
   0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}}
```

Here it is again in `MatrixForm`:

[image]

I would like to join all triplets of sub arrays in each colums so as to have only three long columns an end up with a 2-dimensional array.

Can't seem to find a way using Flatten. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: To put it more plainly, I wish to flatten every column independently.

Comment: @Feyre Nope, this just gives a 2d array with all the small columns next to one another :(

Comment: `Transpose@(Join @@@ Table[list[[i]], {i, 3}]`)

Comment: One way is `Flatten /@ data // Transpose`, there could potentially be even simpler ways.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) can be used to reshape dimensions by making use of its second parameter.

```
Flatten[#, {2, 3}] &@Transpose@data// MatrixForm
```

[`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) places your columns in rows then `Flatten` flattens over dimension 2 (each cell in each row - these contain a sub-list) and then over dimension 3 (each value in each sub-list of each row).  This gives the the three columns you are seeking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 That can simplified to `Flatten[data, {1, 3}] // MatrixForm`.

Comment: @WReach Great improvement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If it isn't closed, it should get an answer.
As far as I can tell the shortest way is

```
Join @@@ list // Transpose
```

or as @C.E. pointed out

```
Flatten /@ list // Transpose
```